# Angularjs Filtering the Field Based on Start Date and End Date?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

Hi all I want to filtering the items like (Start and End Date)  which is based on `Due_date` using the daterange functionality in meanjs app. then I tried many ways but unable to get the solution if any one knows the solution please help me..... [My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/QuJvCXFpKbwVd0OlkHZ2?p=preview)

- Please look at my plunker to reference.
- I Have displaying `Due_date`, so this is the field I want to use for filtering.
- I have used some functionality to add `invoice_Date` and `terms`, which provides the answer like `Due_date`. **for exmple:-** invoice_date : `2016-09-10`, terms : `6`, the answer I got Due_date : `16-09-2016`
- so what I excatly looking for , I want to filter the `Due_date` as start date and end date : **for example:-** if we select start date like `16-09-2016` and end date is `25-09-2016` in table these two transaction only need to display or filter... so I have used daterange filter to achieve this solution, but unable to get the solution please help us.
- the daterange filter is working perfectly if we using ng_module is `invoice_date`, but we don't know how to  filter the `Due_date` filed please help us.... [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QuJvCXFpKbwVd0OlkHZ2?p=preview)

**Controller:**

```
.filter('dateRange', function() {
     return function(records, dateKey, from, to) {
       return records.filter(function(record) {
         return !moment(record[dateKey], 'YYYY-MM-DD').isBefore(moment(from))
                && !moment(record[dateKey], 'YYYY-MM-DD').isAfter(moment(to));
            });
        }
    })
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" ng-model="from">

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" ng-model="to">
```

**Filter:-**

```
ng-repeat="data in  record | dateRange : 'invoice_date' : from : to"
```

This below the filed need to filter in table:-

**Due_date:-**

```
<td> {{addDays(data.invoice_date,data.terms) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
```

- I have created plunker for referrence:- [My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QuJvCXFpKbwVd0OlkHZ2?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom filter  for this

**HTML**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="data in  record | myfilter:from:to">
   <td> {{data.supplier_name}}</td>
   <td> {{data.invoice_date}}</td>
   <td> {{data.terms}}</td>
   <td> {{addDays(data.invoice_date,data.terms) | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
 app.filter("myfilter", function() {
      return function(items, from, to) {
            var df = from;
            var dt =to;
            var result = [];   

            for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                var date = new Date(items[i].invoice_date);
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(items[i].terms));
                var tf = date;
                if (tf > df && tf < dt)  {
                    result.push(items[i]);
                }
            }   
            return result;
      };
    });
```

Comment: thanks for updated plunker...Start date filter is working perfectly, if we select End date it's not showing proper transaction in table..example:- startdate :- 16-09-2016 then if we select end date like 28-09-2016 ,it should need to display three transaction, but only two transaction is displaying in table so please check and update...thanks...

Comment: Please change the month to September first for to date. Currently it is set to October